# Escaping an exclamation mark in a ssh remote call to awk?

Tags: ssh, awk

I have this line:

```
ssh server1 "df -h | sed 's/%/ /g' | awk '{ if (\$5 > 90 && !/^[a-zA-Z]/) { var1=1 }} END { if (var1 == 1) { print 1 } else { print 0 }}'"
```

However, this produces the following error:

```
bash: !/^[a-zA-Z]/: event not found
```

Not quite sure how I should escape the exclamation mark. Any ideas?

Regards,

David

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bash evaluates `!` history manipulation even in double quotes. And if you escape it within quotes you just get `\!` (seriously, wtf bash?). You have to end the double quotes, add either `'!'` or `\!`, and reopen the double quotes.

```
ssh server1 "df ... && "\!"/^[a-zA-Z]/...}}'"
```

For the record, zsh handles the backslash escape within double quotes properly (`"\!"` -> `!`).

Comment: Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? 

`ssh server "awk 'del=(a&&a--) {print; da="\!"a} $0~pattern{if (da) {print "--"; da=0} a=A; if (B) {for(i=NR; i<B+NR; i++) if((i%B) in b) print b[i%B]} {print; da=1}} (B) {if (del) delete b[NR%B]; else b[NR%B]=$0}' B=5 A=2 pattern=Successful file"
 syntax error The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                del=(a&&a--) {print; da=!a} bash~pattern{if (da) {print >>>  --; <<<
 awk: The statement cannot be correctly parsed.
 The source line is 1.
`